# How to get or show every object from newest to latest in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm pretty new to python and django. I was able to create an simple CRUD logic with template, but I have a small problem.

When I update a specific task and then querying all object from a model, the one that was updated is now queried on the last position (views.py below):

```
def create_task(request):
tasks = Task.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_id_update = request.POST.get('task_id_update')
    task_id_delete = request.POST.get('task_id_delete')
    if task_id_update:
        task = Task.objects.filter(id=task_id_update).first()
        task.finished = True
        task.save()
    elif task_id_delete:
        task = Task.objects.filter(id=task_id_delete).first()
        task.delete()
    else:
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save(commit=False)
            task.author = request.user
            task.save()
            return redirect('/create_task')
form = TaskForm()
return render(request, 'main/create_task.html', {'form': form, 'tasks': tasks})
```

And I want to render it on a ONE-PAGE like template, and this is what I did in my html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for task in tasks %}
      {% if task.finished == False %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{task.title}}</td>
          <td>
            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name= "task_id_update" value="{{task.id}}">Mark as finished</button>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name= "task_id_delete" value="{{task.id}}">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% else %}
        <tr class="table-success">
          <td>{{task.title}}</td>
          <td>
            <form method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name= "task_id_delete" value="{{task.id}}">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
      No tasks!
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: to understand what you want to do: do you want the one that updated to now become the first?

Comment: Hey, not exactly. I dont want to change the position of task when i click on Mark as finished button. But what is happening nów, it item that Got clicked goes to the last position and that is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of tasks, during iteration in the for loop, if not explicitly set via an [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) QuerySet method, will be determined by the [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#ordering) Model Meta option. If neither is set, then you'll get the ordering of the values in the database storage. Most databases will just put the last updated record somewhere where it's convenient - at the beginning or the end of the table, for example.

So, you really have several options, but these two stand out:

1. Add `ordering` to your `Task` model's Meta class
2. Add `order_by("FIELD_NAME_HERE", )` to your query, before the `.all()`, on line #2